# How to temporarily save and restore the IFS variable properly?

Tags: shell, variable

How do I correctly run a few commands with an altered value of the `IFS` variable (to change the way field splitting works and how `"$*"` is handled), and then restore the original value of `IFS`?

I know I can do

```bsh
(
    IFS='my value here'
    my-commands here
)
```

to localize the change of `IFS` to the sub-shell, but I don't really want to start a sub-shell, especially not if I need to change or set the values of variables that needs to be visible outside of the sub-shell.

I know I can use

```bsh
saved_IFS=$IFS; IFS='my value here'
my-commands here
IFS=$saved_IFS
```

but that seems to not restore `IFS` correctly in the case that the original `IFS` was actually *unset*.

Looking for answers that are shell agnostic (but POSIX).

Clarification: That last line above means that I'm not interested in a `bash`-exclusive solution.  In fact, the system I'm using most, OpenBSD, does not even come with `bash` installed at all by default, and `bash` is not a shell I use for anything much other than to answer questions on this site. It's much more interesting to see solutions that I may use in `bash` or other POSIX-like shells without making an effort to write non-portable code.

Comment: If you were looking for bash-only answers, I would suggest saving and later `eval`ing the output of `declare -p IFS`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, in `bash` like in all shells with scoping, you'd rather use `local` (though it works best with shells with static scoping or with `zsh`'s `private` instead (not that you'd use `$IFS` in `zsh`)) . The output of bash's `declare -p` is not always safe for `eval`ing.

Comment: ...it's not? I'm surprised about that, would have expected values to be `printf %q`'d or equivalent. Have a reference?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy see [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214). IOW, I wouldn't use `eval` on anything that has been quoted with anything other than the single-quote based approaches there (and even then, it's best to avoid evaling arbitrary data if that can be avoided)

Comment: Similar: [Setting IFS for a single statement](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/92187)

Comment: Also: [When can I use a temporary IFS for field splitting?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/264635)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, mm, I have a hard time telling how that answer (to "Escape a variable for use as content of another script") would tell why `declare -p` within a single Bash script would be a problem? It seems to focus on differences between shells, and mentions a number of different ways for producing quoted versions of a variable, so it's rather hard to pick up what issue you're referring to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, anyway, `declare -p IFS` in itself doesn't work if `IFS` is unset. Then, `declare -p` just errors out with "-bash: declare: IFS: not found". Instead of e.g. printing `unset IFS`.

Comment: Right; but that makes the output a distinguishable state. `unset IFS` before the `eval` and you're fine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, just still means that the unset case needs special treatment with `declare` too. A bit like with the `unset IFS [ -n "${save+set}" ] && IFS=$save;` case below (it's exactly the same workaround of course, since in the other direction you can just `declare -p IFS 2> /dev/null`)

Comment: If it’s only a Single command you can probably also use `IFS=“Xy“ command`

Comment: @ilkkachu, here the output of `declare -p` is not safe to use in a different locale from that where it was generated, like when the part in between the saving and restoring changes the value of `LC_*`/`LANG`... variables. It's also unsafe for some values of `$IFS` in older versions of bash in some locales. Also note that beside the `unset` issue, it can't be used in functions as `declare` would make `IFS` local upon restore. It also won't restore the type to scalar if `IFS` been set to array or hash in between. IOW, it has no advantage over safer approaches.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, in the case when `IFS` is unset, restoring the value from `$saved_IFS` would actually *set* the value of `IFS` (to an empty value).

This would affect the way field splitting of unquoted expansions is done, it would affect field splitting for the `read` built-in utility, and it would affect the way the positional parameters are combined into a string when using `"$*"`.

With an *unset* `IFS` these things would happen *as if* `IFS` had the value of a space, a tab character, and a newline character, but with an *empty* value, there would be no field splitting and the positional parameters would be concatenated into a string  with no delimiter when using `"$*"`.  So, there's a difference.

To correctly restore `IFS`, consider setting `saved_IFS` only if `IFS` is actually set to something.

```bsh
unset saved_IFS
[ -n "${IFS+set}" ] && saved_IFS=$IFS
```

The parameter substitution `${IFS+set}` expands to the string `set` only if `IFS` is set, even if it is set to an empty string.  If `IFS` is unset, it expands to an empty string, which means that the `-n` test would be false and `saved_IFS` would remain unset.

Now, `saved_IFS` is unset if `IFS` was initially unset, or it has the value that `IFS` had, and you can set whatever value you want for `IFS` and run your code.

When restoring `IFS`, you do a similar thing:

```bsh
unset IFS
[ -n "${saved_IFS+set}" ] && { IFS=$saved_IFS; unset saved_IFS; }
```

The final `unset saved_IFS` isn't really necessary, but it may be good to clean up old variables from the environment.

---

An alternative way of doing this, suggested by LL3 in comments (now deleted), relies on prefixing the `unset` command by `:`, a built-in utility that does nothing, effectively commenting out the `unset`, when it's not needed:

```bsh
saved_IFS=$IFS
${IFS+':'} unset saved_IFS
```

This sets `saved_IFS` to the value of `$IFS`, but then unsets it if `IFS` was unset.

Then set `IFS` to your value and run you commands.  Then restore with

```bsh
IFS=$saved_IFS
${saved_IFS+':'} unset IFS
```

(possibly followed by `unset saved_IFS` if you want to clean up that variable too).

Note that `:` must be quoted, as above, or escaped as `\:`, so that it isn't modified by `$IFS` containing `:` (the unquoted parameter substitution invokes field splitting, after all).

Comment: Note that those kinds of approaches are not re-entrant in that for instance, in between the *setting* and *restoring*, you can't call a function that uses the same approach.

Comment: Your `$IFS+:` approach reminds me of https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.shell/c/25QYE-0toQA/m/uFy1F0lEamAJ :-)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.shell/c/00mMle2zpgc/m/L9D42gpVg8QJ is probably where it was invented. You'll notice Laura Fairhead participated in that  thread who coined a few shell idiom pearls.

Comment: The change from `${IFS+:}` to `${IFS:+':'}`  would have been as a work around for older versions of `zsh`, where in `sh` emulation `${IFS+:}` would have expanded to two empty strings if `$IFS` contained `:` (`:` undergoing IFS-splitting)

Answer (score 7):

**Inside a `bash` function, you can use `local IFS=$'\n'`** or whatever to shadow the global (or parent function's `local`) value of `IFS` while inside the scope of this function.  Further assignment to `IFS` will still be modifying your local version.

In `bash`,

> It is an error to use `local` when not within a function.

So this doesn't help if you're not writing a function, or using a shell without `local` (or equivalent), but if you are (and you know `IFS` values you wants at all points until it returns), there is an easy and good solution.

A function doesn't involve a subshell as long as you define it with
`foo(){ ...; }` instead of `foo() ( ... )`.

Comment: `local` isn't POSIX, but Bash/Dash/Busybox do have it. Ksh is a problem here, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Oh, I missed the part of the question that was asking for shell-agnostic / POSIX.  Even so, I wanted to post for future readers who come across this question without that limitation, because it's enough nicer that it's worth knowing about.

Comment: oh I think `local` is an excellent solution, when possible and available. At first, I also thought it was quite portable even, since Dash and Busybox support it too. But then remembered ksh treats them differently. With Bash and others, nested functions may be an issue too, since a function called from one setting `local IFS` will see the "local" value set in the upper function (e.g. `a="main"; bar() { echo "$a"; }; foo() { local a="foo"; bar; }; foo` prints `foo`, not `main`. That's the part that's different in ksh, plus you need `function foo { ... }` there.) So, something to note at least.

Comment: -1 If you have the option of writing a bash script, you also have the option of using a scripting language less terrible than shell.

Comment: @zwol: you can use functions interactively, like `foo(){ IFS=... ; your code here; }; foo`.  I actually do this sometimes if I want to be able to up-arrow / edit, with the thing I want to edit being a function arg without having to move the cursor far back to where its embedded.  (But the function body I want can also change less frequently, so I don't just put it in a file.  In my specific use-case, I have a wrapper function around `mpv` to play 30 minutes or one file, or a couple files, of an audiobook that's either one big file, or one file per CD, or w/e.  I listen while falling asleep)

Comment: @zwol, yeah, that argument could be used for about half the questions and answers on this site. Also, given that `checkbashisms` exists, not every script author seems to have gotten that memo. (sure, it's better nowadays, but, still.)

Comment: @zwol Are you saying that if a question *specifically* asks how to do something *using a shell script* – no, let’s go further, this question *specifically* asks how to do something that *only makes sense in a shell* – we should downvote answers that involve shell scripts?

Comment: @BrianDrake: No, zwol seems to be arguing that the only reason to write a shell script is portability, which means only using POSIX `sh` features.  (And only features that aren't known to be buggy on any important shells, see zwol's answer).  With that mindset, there's never a reason to write bash-only scripts.  (This is of course flawed logic; e.g. autocomplete scripts are very shell-specific, and for performance and other reasons are written in the shell's own language.)

Comment: @zwol The shell is not a terrible scripting language for getting simple things done. It's a terrible _generic_ language. My approach to shell scripting is to use POSIX syntax until a specific shell's features clearly make things easier. In this simple case of saving and restoring a shell variable, I fail to see that any shell has an exclusive feature that makes this much easier than any other POSIX-like shell. This is partly why I'm asking for a POSIX solution.  Having said that, using `local` is a _good_ solution, albeit not POSIX. `local` is _often_ implemented, in one way or another.

Comment: (cont.) The issue with `local` is that since it's not POSIX, one has to also mention how it can be used and not used. What are the failure conditions? What corner cases does this not work in? Does all shells that have `local`, or `typeset` or similar, deal with it the same way?

Comment: @Kusalananda, about that, see [List of shells that support \`local\` keyword for defining local variables](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/493729)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, my position is that the _only_ time one should ever write a bash-specific script is to extend the bash interactive environment (and similarly for e.g. zsh, fish).

Comment: @Kusalananda Bourne shell is a terrible language, period.

Answer (score 4):

In sufficiently old shells, `unset` either doesn't exist at all or is unusably buggy (comments in Autoconf's source code say that `unset IFS` may *crash the process*). Kusalananda's answer cannot be used with such shells.

If you have to worry about shells this old, your best bet is to set IFS to a space, a tab, and a newline, in that order, as early as possible:

```
# There is a hard tab between the second pair of single quotes.
IFS=' ''    ''
'
```

This setting has the same effect as an unset IFS, but it can be safely saved and restored with the second construct from the question:

```
saved_IFS="$IFS"; IFS='my value here'
my commands here
IFS="$saved_IFS"
```

(Double-quoting the right hand side of `variable=$othervariable` is technically not necessary, but it makes life easier for everyone who might have to read your shell script in the future if you don't make them remember that.)

Comment: +1 Simple, shell agnostic and double-quotes the variable expansions (which the question and other answers failed to do). I suggest you add an explanation about that last point.

Comment: @BrianDrake, note that `foo=$bar` is one of the cases where double-quoting is _not_ necessary. (bar e.g. some earlier buggy cases with Certain Shells.)

Comment: Can you mention a shell that does not have `unset`? Would this be a POSIX shell?

Comment: @Kusalananda POSIX does require `unset`.  The problem is, `/bin/sh` on several of the most popular surviving proprietary Unixes *isn't POSIX compliant* -- its behavior was intentionally frozen *without* the changes required by Unix95.  And since `/bin/sh` is the only shell that is guaranteed to exist, and the one run by `system` and similar...

Comment: @BrianDrake I am not sure what you meant by "add an explanation about that last point" but I've done my best to address what I think you are asking for.

Comment: You're talking about Solaris 10?

Comment: @Kusalananda Among others.

Comment: @zwol Sorry, but I'm intrigued. What other current popular commercial Unix contains an original Bourne shell? The Korn shell playing the role of `sh` on AIX has no issue with its `unset` AFAIK. Only the old SunOS `sh` on Solaris is _documented_ to not be able to unset `IFS` (or `PATH`, or `MAILCHECK` or the prompt variables). macOS `sh` is `bash`, so there should be no issue there.

Comment: @zwol At the time, I thought that the quoting *was* necessary. But now I see that word splitting is not performed in assignments.

Comment: @Kusalananda I may be out of date, but I thought AIX still relegated the Unix95-compliant shell environment to a non-default path, like Solaris does with `/usr/xpg4`.  And I'm not sure HP-UX or Digital Unix qualifiy as "current" -- it's no longer my job to know if anyone supports those anymore -- but they definitely did the same thing last I used them (which was about seven years ago now).

Comment: I based my AIX comment on the [`sh(1)` manual from AIX 7.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/s_commands/sh.html). Tru64 reached end of life in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, I'd do it this way:

```bsh
[ -v IFS ] && oldIFS="$IFS" || unset oldIFS

IFS=something
some commands

[ -v oldIFS ] && IFS="$oldIFS" || unset IFS
```

or this way:

```bsh
[ "${IFS+set}" ] && oldIFS="$IFS" || unset oldIFS

IFS=something
some commands

[ "${oldIFS+set}" ] && IFS="$oldIFS" || unset IFS
```

Comment: Did you mean `[[` instead of `[`? Your answer mentions Bash and according to the manpage [(1) on my system, there is no `-v` test.

Comment: @Brian Drake:  Did you try it?  I never had a reason to look into `[[`.

Comment: From reading the `bash` manpage more carefully, it turns out that it has its own version of `[`, which supports the same tests as `[[`. I do not understand why there are two forms, nor how POSIX-compatible either of them is.

Comment: Anyway, both `[` and `[[` work in `bash --posix`. Perhaps my new question should be: Why did you mention Bash at all? The question asked for a shell-agnostic answer.

Comment: @BrianDrake: `[[` is part of the shell grammar so it can affect how var expansion works inside it, making it more robust for some cases with vars whole value is `-n` for example, and allowing other features; I forget all the details of why it's better.  `[` is "just" a command.

Comment: @BrianDrake Running `bash` in POSIX mode does not _disable_ all non-POSIX features.  The fact that `[[` works in POSIX mode in `bash` does not mean that `[[` is a POSIX feature.  The fact that it's not mentioned in the POSIX standard (other than "causing unspecified result") means it's not a POSIX feature. It's _allowed_ to be interpreted (in an unspecified way) by a shell running in POSIX mode.

Comment: @BrianDrake the _man page_ probably describes the external version of `[`. It probably doesn't have `-v` because it would not be nearly as useful in an external program than in a shell builtin. In Bash, use `help test`. Also see e.g. [How do I know if the man page I'm looking at is the correct one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460567/170373)

Answer (score 0):

#### copy

The initial goal is to copy a variable (`a`) to another (`b`).
Doing a simple `b=$a` works if `a` is set (either a "" or a value), but if `a` is unset, `b` needs to be unset as well. If not, `b` will be set to "".

An unset IFS works differently than a null IFS (in bash):

```
                             $' \t\n'      unset         null("")
Split Expansions             default       default       no splitting
join arguments with "$*"     "$1c$2c..."   "$1 $2 ..."   "$1$2"
```

So, we need two steps, copy the value and unset the copied variable (if needed). A variable copy from `a` to `b` could be done in several ways:

```
if [ -n "${a+set}" ]; then unset b; else b="$a"; fi
[ -n "${a+set}" ] && unset b || b="$a"
[ "${a+set}" ] && unset b || b="$a"

${a+'false'} && b=$a || unset b
```

Then, for IFS, we can copy it to oldIFS, change the value of IFS as needed, and restore it after use:

```
${IFS+'false'} && oldIFS=$IFS || unset oldIFS

IFS='new value'

${oldIFS+'false'} && IFS=$oldIFS || unset IFS
```

#### function(s)

The only way to improve this is to use a function, and yes, a function would be able to copy two vars:

```
copyIFS    () { ${IFS+'false'} && oldIFS=$IFS || unset oldIFS; }
```

provided that the names of the variables to modify are known before writing the function as the function must access such variables at the **global** scope. No `local` possible, no use of `declare/typeset`.

It is not possible in `sh` to create a function for `copyvars var1 var2` (with var1 and var2 variable). That would require the use of named vars.

The restore function (using the swapped variable names) is:

```
restoreIFS () { ${oldIFS+'false'} && IFS=$oldIFS || unset IFS; }
```

Defining those two functions, we can do:

```
copyIFS
IFS='a new value'
restoreIFS
```

Probably simpler, less prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but in zsh you can also use an anonymous function.

```
myArray=($'\1', $'\1')
printf "before: "
typeset -p IFS
function {

   local IFS=$'\0'
   joinedArray=${(j::)myArray}

   printf "during: "
   typeset -p IFS
}

printf "after: "
typeset -p IFS
```

This prints:

```
before: typeset IFS=$' \t\n\C-@'
during: typeset IFS=$'\C-@'
after: typeset IFS=$' \t\n\C-@'
```

So the value of `IFS` is restored. I'm guessing this is probably more lightweight than a subshell.