# Is there a method to indicate the last iteration in a loop over lines of an input file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Suppose I have a file `direction` with the lines

```
east
north
south
west
south-west
```

and using a loop and `echo` in a shell script I want to generate this  output:

```
Direction: east
Direction: north
Direction: south
Direction: west
Last direction: south-west
```

So in other words I want to do something different with the last line in the script.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`bash` can't detect the end of a file (without trying to read the next line and failing), but perl can with its `eof` function:

```
$ perl -n -e 'print "Last " if eof; print "Direction: $_"' direction 
Direction: east
Direction: north
Direction: south
Direction: west
Last Direction: south-west
```

note: unlike `echo` in bash, the `print` statement in perl doesn't print a newline unless you either 1. explicitly tell it to by including `\n` in the string you're printing, or 2. are using perl's `-l` command-line option, or 3. if the string already contains a newline....as is the case with `$_` - which is why you often need to `chomp()` it to get rid of the newline.

BTW, in perl, `$_` is the current input line. Or the default iterator (often called "the current thingy" probably because "dollarunderscore" is a bit of a mouthful) in any loop that doesn't specify an actual variable name. **Many** perl functions and operators use `$_` as their default/implicit argument if one isn't provided. See `man perlvar` and search for `$_`.

`sed` can too - the `$` address matches the last line of a file:

```
$ sed -e 's/^/Direction: /; $s/^/Last /' direction 
Direction: east
Direction: north
Direction: south
Direction: west
Last Direction: south-west
```

The order of the `sed` rules is important.  My first attempt did it the wrong way around (and printed "Direction: Last south-west").   This sed script always adds "Direction: " to the beginning of each line.  On the last line (`$`) it adds "Last " to the beginning of the line already modified by the previous statement.

Comment: BTW, there's one major but non-obvious difference between the perl and sed versions.   If given multiple input files, the perl version will print "Last Direction: " for the last line of each and every input file.  The sed version will only print "Last Direction:" for the very last line of the entire input.   You can get perl to behave like sed by using `eof()` instead of just `eof`....see `perldoc -f eof` for why.   To get sed to behave like perl does, use the `-s` option - `sed -s -e '.....'` - this is a GNU extension to sed and may or may not be available in other versions.

Comment: If your listing all the ways in perl to add a newline when printing, theres also `use v5.10;` and then use the `say` function instead of print, which always appends a newline.

Comment: @user1937198 i wasn't, really. it was about `print`.  That para was explaining why the print function works to do what the OP wants - it doesn't output a newline unless you tell it to, which makes it useful to print a single line in stages. In shell, you'd have to use `printf` with a format string without a newline (you can't rely on the many incompatible variations of `echo` that offer different ways of doing that).   perl's `say` is a similar but different function...and btw, you can just use `-E` instead of `-e` to enable it, which is less typing than `use v5.10;` or `-Mv5.10`.

Comment: I would prefer skipping the `print` and using a separate substitution for the last line. (So that it also works when the last substitution doesn't  contain the first):`perl -pne 'if(eof) { s/^/Last Direction: /; } else { s/^/Direction: /; }' direction`

Comment: @Garo [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Answer (score 16):

The loop cannot know when it gets to the end unless it actually gets to the end.  So either you process your file twice, once to get the number of lines and another to output, or you print out the previous value on each iteration and the last one on exiting the loop:

```bsh
prev=""
while read direction; do 
    if [ -n "$prev" ]; then 
        echo "Direction: $prev"
    fi
    prev="$direction"
done < direction
echo "Last Direction: $prev"
```

Comment: `prev` would be a less confusing name for that variable, IMO.  You're doing this to handle the last iteration specially, but that variable is used all the time, not just on the last iteration.  `if [ -n "$last" ]` is checking for the *first* iteration, i.e. no previous iteration, not for last or non-last.  (Also, another way to do this might be to peel the first `read` out of the loop, but bash doesn't have C-style `do{}while` loops that would naturally work with a `read` at the bottom.  And you'd have to separately check the first read for EOF if you can't assume non-empty input.)

Comment: lol, I was using _last_ in its meaning of _previous_ ("last week"), it didn't occur to me that it would be read as meaning _final_. It's obvious in retrospect, of course, but I didn't see it. Thanks, @PeterCordes!

Comment: It often takes a 2nd person to find a way to misinterpret something you or I wrote, totally normal :P  But yeah, since "Last Direction" was already right there in the problem, that's where my brain went on first reading, before seeing that you'd rotated the loop to allow peeling the part of the last iteration we want to do differently.  (And thus to see that you were using that meaning of "last")

Answer (score 10):

A variation of [FelixJN's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672880/52164), reading the lines into an array, but using bash builtins instead of bash loops:

```
mapfile -t DIR < direction
printf "Direction: %s\n" "${DIR[@]::${#DIR[@]}-1}"
printf "Last direction: %s\n" "${DIR[-1]}"
```

[mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) is a builtin added in Bash 4 which reads standard input into an array with one line per entry. The `-t` option strips the newlines.

`printf` will apply its format string repeatedly until it has used up all its
input arguments.

Comment: This seems by far the fastest, at least according to `time`.

Answer (score 7):

You may read in the values into an array and then use the array length:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read line ; do
  arr[$i]="$line"
  ((i++))
done <file

for (( i=0 ; i<=${#arr[@]}-2 ; i++ )) ; do
  echo Direction: ${arr[i]}
done
echo Last direction: ${arr[-1]}
```

Of course this means having all data in RAM.

The simpler `arr=( $(cat file) )` would only work if the line entries do not have spaces, thus I used a `while read`-loop here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a mix of `paste`, `tail` and `head`:

```
$ paste -s -d'\n' <(head -n -1 direction | sed 's/^/Direction: /') <(tail -n1 direction | sed 's/^/Last direction: /')
Direction: east
Direction: north
Direction: south
Direction: west
Last direction: south-west
```

---

- `paste -s -d'\n'` uses new line as delimiter with the option `-d'\n'`, and the option `-s`:

  > -s, --serial
  > paste one file at a time instead of in parallel
- `head -n -1` retrieves all lines but the last, then is piped to `sed` to perform the command you need in those lines only.
- `tail -n1 file` retrieves the last line of the file, then is piped to `sed` to perform the command you need in that line only.

---

Or more succintly just using `cat` instead of `paste`, as noted by [@Mick Matteo's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672871/is-there-a-method-to-indicate-the-last-occurrence-of-the-loop/672891#comment1269823_672891):

```
$ cat <(head -n -1 direction | sed 's/^/Direction: /') <(tail -n1 direction | sed 's/^/Last direction: /')
```

Comment: Why not just `cat` (con**cat**enate) instead of `paste -s -d'\n'`?

Comment: @NickMatteo right! added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answers by [FelixJN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672880/315749) and [Nick Matteo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672938/315749): using [portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/posix/info) shell features (noting that the question has no shell-specific tags) and assuming you are processing a controlled, "small-enough" set of lines, you can know when the loop reaches its last element if you place the data into the array of positional parameters:

```bsh
IFS='
'
set -f
set -- $(cat direction)
for dir
do
  if [ $(( i = i + 1 )) -eq "$#" ]
  then
    printf '%s' 'Last direction: '
  else
    printf '%s' 'Direction: '
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$dir"
done
```

Keep in mind that you may want to properly [restore `IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640062/315749) after setting it.

Note, however, that this will remove any empty input lines from the output. If you are not fine with this, you can load the array of positional parameters in a loop:

```
set --
while IFS= read -r line
do
  set -- "$@" "$line"
done <direction
```

(No need to set `IFS` to a newline and `set -f` in this case).

---

The approach from the answers by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672877/315749) (`sed` part) and [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672876/315749) — handle the last element "outside" the loop — can also be implemented in AWK using a quite common pattern:

```bsh
awk '
  NR > 1 { print "Direction: " dir }
  { dir = $0 }
  END { if (NR > 0) print "Last direction: " dir }
' direction
```

Answer (score 1):

A different strategy: note that the last line of your file is the first line of your reversed file. So, instead of relying on line indices, you can use a basic `echo` loop if you reverse the order of lines in your file with `tac`, [which is part of coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tac-invocation.html). Then, reverse the order of your loop output to retrieve the original order.

```
prefix='Last direction:'
while read line; do
   echo "$prefix $line"
   prefix='Direction:'
done < <(tac direction) | tac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col=`awk 'END{print NR}' filename`
awk -v co="$col" '{if (NR<co){print "Direction: "$0}else{print "Last direction: "$0}}' filename

output

Direction: east
Direction: north
Direction: south
Direction: west
Last direction: south-west
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop over the lines and delay printing the lines by one iteration: we print the previous line stored from a variable (`prev` in the code below) and then store the current line into this variable afterwards.  Once the loop is finished, we have the last line in `prev` and can print it with its special prefix:

```
#! /bin/sh
prev=""
first="yes"
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/648741
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]; do
  if [ "$first" = "yes" ]; then
    first="no"
  else
    printf 'Direction: %s\n' "$prev"
  fi
  prev="$p"
done < directions
if [ "$first" = "no" ]; then
    printf 'Last direction: %s\n' "$prev"
fi
```

The code here takes some extra care to not damage whitespace and to allow for dollar signs within the lines.  If this is not needed, a simpler version also works:

```
#! /bin/sh
prev=""
while read -r p; do
  if [ -n "$prev" ]; then
    echo "Direction: $prev"
  fi
  prev="$p"
done < directions
if [ -n "$prev" ]; then
    echo "Last direction: $prev"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e 'my $fh = $*ARGFILES.IO.open; $fh.eof ?? put("Last direction: $_") !! put("Direction: $_") for $fh.lines; $fh.close;' file.txt
```

OR

```
raku -e 'my $fh = $*ARGFILES.IO.open; for $fh.lines() { if not $fh.eof { put "Direction: $_" } else { put "Last direction: $_" };}; $fh.close;' file.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
east
north
south
west
south-west
```

Sample Output:

```
Direction: east
Direction: north
Direction: south
Direction: west
Last direction: south-west
```

Currently, Raku implements a `.eof` method which operates on either `IO::Handle` or `IO::CatHandle` objects and *"...returns `True` if the read operations have exhausted the contents of the handle... ."*

The first code example above uses Raku's ternary operator `$condition ?? $true !! $false` to test whether `$fh.eof` is `True`. Note above for both code examples how `.eof` operates directly on the `$fh` filehandle scalar, whereas `$_` gets loaded with retrieved (line-wise) data, which is printed using `put` (or `say`, if desired).

Note, the rather simplistic code examples above only work on a single file at a time at the `bash` command line. However it's likely that feeding a list of files to `$fh` (for example via Raku's `dir()` method) may be the best way to manipulate multiple files at once.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/eof
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
https://raku.org